# How can you access the completely rendered DOM source of a URL with PHP?

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom

I'd like to access the rendered DOM of a page, after JavaScript has run and modified the page source, with PHP. I can access the raw code with CURL, but what I;d like is to access the code similar to the way Firefox's Examine Element feature works, so I can process the actual HTML output by Javascript functions and not just the Javascript code itself. Are there any PHP libraries that can do this?

Comment: When do you consider a page complete?

Comment: And when you say `Examine Element`, you mean `Inspect Element`, right?

Comment: Yeah, I was looking at Chrome's version when I wrote the question.

Comment: @icktofofay, all I need ois to be able to parse the HTML output by any executed Javascript functions.

Comment: @MarathonStudios: The problem is that JavaScript doesn't just modify the DOM at page load; it can continue to modify the DOM after page load. As such, there is no way to tell when the JavaScript is "done".

Comment: @MarathonStudios: And while I suppose you could wait until it stopped modifying the DOM, there are some scripts that will *never* stop modifying the DOM (like a clock).

Comment: I don't think you can do this. Javascript is run in the client  and may or may not be turned on. Even if you access your 'finished' page with curl or file_get_contents() the javascript will not run. So, you have no way of accessing the post javascript version of the page through PHP. However, it may be possible to get javascript to send the completed version of the page back to the server with an AJAX call?

Comment: What that means is that you need to provide a runtime environment for Javascript to run in and a DOM to work on. So what you need is a headless browser environment, accessible and scriptable from PHP. Look into the Webkit core and things like that but be advised that it's a very non-trivial problem. What do you *really* want to achieve with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the ["headless browser" section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/headless-browser).

It's a good place to start.